# Bootstrap- highlight Active and Angular directive

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make selected item on Bootstrap navbar highlighted.
Here is my code:

```
<ul  class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left" top-bar>
```

and directive:

```
a.directive('topBar', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        $(elem).on("click", function () {
            $(elem).find(".active").removeClass("active");
            $(this).parent().addClass("active");
        });
    }
}
```

});

It only works if I remove class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left". Otherwise, it's not getting into the directive. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to listen clicks on list items (tag `li`) in the component and update its classes. Try to use [event delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) – if you are using jQuery, just add extra selector into `on` call:

```
a.directive('topBar', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.on("click", "li", function (e) {
                elem.find(".active").removeClass("active");
                $(this).addClass("active");
            });
         }
    };
});
```

Comment: >Try to use event delegation< That was it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

use this code. may be it's help you...

```
app.directive('topBar', function () {
  return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
          $(elem).on("click", function () {
            $(".active").removeClass("active");
            $(elem).addClass("active");

          });
      }
   }
});
```

[see this link](http://plnkr.co/edit/eoFnPjZgOHs4HILHy8lF?p=preview)

Comment: `$(".active")` is so global. That removes all `active` classes on the page

Comment: use this.

    ` $(elem).parent().find(".active").removeClass("active");`